# Facing ‘Error: Cannot find module’ when running npm run dev command in Laravel 8. How to fix it?

Tags: php, node.js, vue.js

i hope you guys are doing good.my issue is when i run npm run dev command on terminal.facing this issue.my laravel version is 8.83.27 and node version is 18.14.0.

[image]

I have done everything within my abilities, such as deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json files, and then running the npm install command again. However, the bug still persists. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked `scripts` in `package.json`?

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable. The use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-mix\bin\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}